# Visual Studio Code can't #include libraries from other paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

using Windows.
I've been using CodeBlocks to code C++ and I have no problem including header files from outside the folder like
`#include <boost\algorithm\string.hpp>`
I have been trying to edit and run the same source codes with Visual Studio Code. I installed the Visual Studio Code C++ extension. I red that there are two places where the user can modify the include path.
In the settings.json file and in the c_cpp_properties.json.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1cjG.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6ZDI.png

I tried adding a line in both but I doesn't work.
I keep on getting the

> main.cpp:10:10: fatal error: boost\algorithm\string.hpp: No such file or directory

What can I be doing wrong? Backslashes?
What is better practice for Visual Studio Code users? Modifying the local c_cpp_properties.json or the more general settings.json?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1cjG.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6ZDI.png

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses backslashes, whereas other operating systems use forward slashes. Since backslashes are also used for escape characters like newline - `'\n'`, you need to escape the backslash using double backslashes - `'\\'`

```
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
       "C:\\Program Files\\Cpp_libs\\boost_1_75_0\\"
   ],
```

Once the include path is added, all following 3 should work

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost\algorithm\string.hpp>
#include <boost\\algorithm\\string.hpp>
```

It depends on whether you want to apply these settings to all the workspaces, or only the current one, so you can add accordingly.

---